# Digital up conversion and digital down conversion

Tags: digital-communications, sampling

Description:

I’m trying to use the standard sample rate of 61.44 MSPS on both sides of my digital transceiver(DUC and DDC,) so I’ll upsample my data from baseband data rate 3.84 MSPS to 61.44 MSPS with a factor of 16 in DUC procedure and downsample the received 61.44 MSPS by a factor of 8 to 7.68 MSPS (the ADC and DAC are excluded for testing). As shown in photos from Xilinx DUC and DDC recommendation:

DUC:

[image]

DDC:

[image]

At the input of the DUC mixer, the I and Q data rate is equal to 61.44 MSPS. I’ll apply a cos(ω_0 n + φ) on the I arm and sin (ω_0 n + φ) on the Q arm of the DUC side, and repeat the same procedure on the DDC side and after DDC I apply a low pass filter to reject the high-frequency part of the downconverted signal.

If one sets the frequency (not sample time) of the DDC oscillator to f_IF=61.44 MSPS or 61.44 MHz so that the center frequency of the desired band will be translated to DC to avoid any need for an image rejection filter for the DDC mixers.

The  DUC and DDC mixers are identical. I used the lowest possible sample per period=4 for my sine and cosine wave representation as shown below   e^(j π/2 n)=cos(π/2 n)+ jsin(π/2 n) for n=0,1,2,3.

Problem:

1. When I set the sample time of my DUC’s and DDC’s NCOs to 1/f_IF=1/61.44e6=1.6276e-08 then I have the same data rate at the multiplication (mixer) block. Therefore, the output sample rate of the mixer is 61.44 MSPS but the frequency of my sine and cosine waves are 15.35 MHz as shown below, which is not the same as IF frequency (61.44 MHz) to bring the desired signal to DC.

[image]

NCO(discrete sine wave) output frequency with 4 samples per period, sample time=1/f_IF

[image]

Wrong LO frequency but correct mixer output sample rate.

2. If I set the sample time of my DUC’s and DDC’s NCOs to 1 / (4 * f_IF)  with NCO configured for 4 samples per period I get the correct LO frequency=61.44 MHz but the data rate at the mixer output will be 4*61.44= 245.76 MSPS which is not correct according to Xilinx's received data rate at DDC.

[image]
Correct LO frequency but the mixer output sample rate is wrong.

For clarification the complete data flow is shown below:

[image]

Complete data flow

Please note that the ADC and DAC are excluded from the chain, therefore DDC receives the samples directly from DUC.

I would be grateful if one can suggest the correct way of generating LO in a way that it translates (by mixing) the desired signal center frequency to DC (to avoid image rejection.)

Comment: You asked this on dsp.se yesterday. Please don't cross post.

Comment: I'm a new se member, I thought the members are different!

Comment: They usually are different.  But we like there to be single question/answer thread for a given question, in order to avoid partial answers in multiple forums that someone has to stich together,